# Added A Button To Second Activity In Android To Return To First. Now App Crashes When Navigating To Second Activity

Tags: java, android, xml, button, crash

Having a bit of trouble with my app. I'm in the beginning stages of making a game and I have a simple instructions page that was running fine. That is until I added a button at the bottom to return to the homepage. Now when I click the link to the instructions page the app crashes. I looked around and can only find people who haven't added the activity to the manifest which I have done. Please help...

Code for button to return.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;

public class HowTo extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setContentView(R.layout.how_to);

Button btnHomeFromHow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnHomeFromHow);
btnHomeFromHow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


    public void onClick(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(HowTo.this, Home.class));
    }
});
```

Manifest.

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.whackachav"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.whackachav.Home"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity 
        android:name="com.example.whackachav.HowTo"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.Main" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    <activity 
        android:name="com.example.whackachav.Game"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity 
        android:name="com.example.whackachav.HighScores"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>   
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Button in layout file.

```
        <button
        android:id="@+id/btnHomeFromHow"
        style="@style/btnStyleShakespeare"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvBucky"
        android:text="Back to Main Menu"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />
```

log.

```
12-13 16:05:25.560: E/Trace(2397): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-13 16:05:26.260: D/dalvikvm(2397): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 53K, 8% free 2456K/2652K, paused 42ms, total 44ms
12-13 16:05:26.431: D/dalvikvm(2397): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2K, 7% free 2909K/3112K, paused 82ms+4ms, total 156ms
12-13 16:05:27.100: D/gralloc_goldfish(2397): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-13 16:05:27.740: I/Choreographer(2397): Skipped 84 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-13 16:05:35.921: D/dalvikvm(2397): GC_CONCURRENT freed 30K, 5% free 3349K/3524K, paused 79ms+8ms, total 210ms
12-13 16:05:35.921: D/dalvikvm(2397): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 39ms
12-13 16:05:36.160: D/dalvikvm(2397): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 50K, 6% free 3546K/3772K, paused 47ms, total 55ms
12-13 16:05:36.170: I/dalvikvm-heap(2397): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.213MB for 643068-byte allocation
12-13 16:05:36.240: D/dalvikvm(2397): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 4174K/4404K, paused 64ms, total 64ms
12-13 16:05:36.360: D/dalvikvm(2397): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 6% free 4174K/4404K, paused 5ms+17ms, total 117ms
12-13 16:05:36.721: D/dalvikvm(2397): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 4178K/4404K, paused 44ms, total 52ms
12-13 16:05:36.740: I/dalvikvm-heap(2397): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.942MB for 760600-byte allocation
12-13 16:05:36.950: D/dalvikvm(2397): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 5% free 4920K/5148K, paused 85ms+4ms, total 210ms
12-13 16:05:37.330: D/AndroidRuntime(2397): Shutting down VM
12-13 16:05:37.340: W/dalvikvm(2397): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
12-13 16:05:37.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2397): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-13 16:05:37.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2397): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.whackachav/com.example.whackachav.HowTo}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #101: Error inflating class button
12-13 16:05:37.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2397):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
12-13 16:05:37.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2397):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
12-13 16:05:37.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2397):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-13 16:05:37.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2397):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
12-13 16:05:37.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2397):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-13 16:05:37.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2397):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-13 16:05:37.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2397):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
12-13 16:05:37.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2397):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-13 16:05:37.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2397):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-13 16:05:37.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2397):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-13 16:05:37.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2397):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-13 16:05:37.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2397):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-13 16:05:37.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2397): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #101: Error inflating class button
12-13 16:05:37.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2397):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
12-13 16:05:37.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2397):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
12-13 16:05:37.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2397):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
12-13 16:05:37.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2397):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
12-13 16:05:37.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2397):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
12-13 16:05:37.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2397):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
12-13 16:05:37.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2397):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
12-13 16:05:37.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2397):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
12-13 16:05:37.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2397):     at com.example.whackachav.HowTo.onCreate(HowTo.java:15)
12-13 16:05:37.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2397):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
12-13 16:05:37.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2397):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
12-13 16:05:37.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2397):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
12-13 16:05:37.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2397):     ... 11 more
12-13 16:05:37.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2397): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.button" on path: /data/app/com.example.whackachav-1.apk
12-13 16:05:37.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2397):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
12-13 16:05:37.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2397):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
12-13 16:05:37.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2397):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
12-13 16:05:37.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2397):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
12-13 16:05:37.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2397):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:643)
12-13 16:05:37.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2397):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
12-13 16:05:37.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2397):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
12-13 16:05:37.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2397):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
12-13 16:05:37.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2397):     ... 22 more
12-13 16:05:39.780: I/Process(2397): Sending signal. PID: 2397 SIG: 9
```

Comment: have you declared `Home` Activity in manifest?

Comment: Yeah, probably should have mentioned that. Home is the first activity that was created when I started so it's in there by default.

    <activity
            android:name="com.example.whackachav.Home"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category     android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: Where is your crash log ?

Comment: @user3099929 use `HomeTo.this` instead of `getApplicationContext()` and make sure button is in `how_to.xml` and why did you make HomeTo a launcher?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to android development. What exactly is it you're looking for?

Comment: @Raghunandan eclipse set it to that as a default

Comment: @user3099929 post full manifest and mention which activity you want as launcher ie launched by default.

Comment: @Raghunandan I've now posted the full manifest with the changes recommended below to everything that shouldn't be LAUNCHER. I tried changing the code like you suggested but it is still crashing.

Comment: @user3099929 now post stack trace. open Window- open perspective- open DDMS- open logcat. You will see a exception part. Extract that post it here.

Comment: @user3099929 show us your xml where button is it should be <B not <b

Comment: Oh dear... I can't believe it. It's always the little things isn't it? I capitalized <button/> and everything is now as it should be. This is embarrassing... Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<button
        android:id="@+id/btnHomeFromHow"
        style="@style/btnStyleShakespeare"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvBucky"
        android:text="Back to Main Menu"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />
```

To

```
<Button  // B in caps
    android:id="@+id/btnHomeFromHow"
    style="@style/btnStyleShakespeare"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/tvBucky"
    android:text="Back to Main Menu"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define the Home.java class in Android Manifest.
 so try this.

```
<activity 
    android:name="com.example.whackachav.Home"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use..

"android.intent.category.DEFAULT"

for HowTo

if you are using LAUNCHER for Home

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be here:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.button" on path: /data/app/com.example.whackachav-1.apk
```

which is likely caused by:

```
<button
        android:id="@+id/btnHomeFromHow"
        style="@style/btnStyleShakespeare"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvBucky"
        android:text="Back to Main Menu"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />
```

Because "button" should actually be "Button" with a capital B.

Also, possibly unrelated, but depending on how you started the "HowTo" activity, it may be better to simply call [finish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) instead of trying to start the Home activity again.